# Raphael Js SVG text element and MathJax rendering

Tags: javascript, svg, latex, raphael, mathjax

I am using Rapaheljs for plot creation and in the visual, I have dynamic text element which can have math functions or special chars. In order to get math formatting I am using MathJax, however, **it seems post rendering it eats up the equation part**. Here is the code -

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.js"></script>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        showProcessingMessages: false,
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']] }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
          var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('container'), 100, 100);
            var text = paper.text( 20, 20, "Hello $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$" );
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, text[0]])
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Can someone point out whats the issue? Is there any other way to achieve this or my MathJax configuration is an issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML code inside SVG Text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946604/insert-html-code-inside-svg-text-element)

Comment: Alternatively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962325/mathjax-inside-svg